# Elastic Search data lost/erased/removed

Tags: elasticsearch

I indexed around 50000 videos in elastic search, but when it reaches around 52000 , all data was erased. Well that was really weird for me, i had not set any Heap size or min or max size memory size for ES so they were defaut i.e 256m min and 1g max and my total size of the document is 304mb. I have not changed anything else from default as i am still like in a learning stag of elastic search so any idea what could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lucene under the hood is highly resilient.

IMHO the only reasons of such a deletion come from the user himself.
Someone on your Network probably send a delete command such as:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200
```

You should add more details on your configuration here.

- How do you send docs?
- What does your elasticsearch.yml looks like?
- How many nodes in your cluster?

Comment: I was waiting to recreate the problem, i still have 375M of data in /elasticsearc/data folder , i can see it in head plugin but nothing is working when i am doing search via php , i can give you all info with excess, i am not very good with elasticsearch configs and info, please tell me your skypeid , you can post the solution later here.

Comment: This is really strange. We can see that you had huge amount of merges. Sounds like you are sending big binary content to ES. Is it what you really want to do: storing videos?

Comment: That said, I will talk with our team about that one. What are your ES version, java version?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.8.0.el6_4-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

No i am not storing videos just there information, title, tags, description and few other related text.

Data directory size of ES is ~350Mb

Comment: Basically i am updating 'score' field everytime a query is called. May be i am doing something wrong?

Comment: You did not give your ES version. First, upgrade to latest 0.20.6. Then, could you paste your logs if the problem still occur?

Comment: its 0.20.6, when i restarted the instances i can see search has starting to show but 50% docs seems missing and i have not sent any delete command. now es data directory size is reduced to 237M and after few minutes it was reduced to 218M
elasticsearch.yml has # on each line which means default configs are being used. I can give you full access for the server.

Comment: Hi Arslan, could you post your log files and give your number of open file handlers?

Comment: Also, can you give your exact scenario. What kind of documents are you sending? How do you send it? Could share a GIST of the exact command you are running? Are you updating docs? Are you only injecting? No search at all at the same time?

Comment: I do it via elastica php plugin,

Comment: I do it via elastica php plugin
Here is the mapping
http://pastebin.com/7SsEXdH5

Here is how i index videos
http://pastebin.com/Gu7HJrT0

Here is how i update video score
http://pastebin.com/ETNGDuEP

Here are the logs file
https://mega.co.nz/#!OkIiSQRI!FmPPDiLgjMt30z4VFO-MQQs4y8k8Mwn8PLUg4wYjk7w


Before max file handler was 4075 and now i have changed it to 65514

- I am indexing + Search + Updating...all at once...

Comment: So you are not only "indexing"! Your description was really incorrect.
I don't know elastica but something is really weird. Sounds like you are doing refresh all the time. Don't do that! Never!

Comment: Oh, yes, i refresh my index everytime add a new document, so its really bad? Let me extract json code how i am mapping/indexing/updating

Comment: Mapping : http://pastebin.com/kaY3QVDY

AGain, yes i refresh all the time should i stop it now? and this script i use when i add score

http://pastebin.com/iAYSiwga

Comment: As I wrote just before: "Don't do that! Never!". So yes stop refreshing all time and let Elasticsearch do its job. Do you really need realtime search or Realtime get? Why do you think you need to refresh?
Try to rerun your test without refreshing and see where it goes.

Comment: i am updating fields and it also does the refresh? i have removed all other refreshing though...merge size has reached over 41gig..what do you suggest?

Comment: Can you create a small curl recreation of all what you are doing from scratch (delete index, create index, create mapping, push one doc, push another doc, update doc one, update doc two)?

Comment: BTW, did you reinject everything from scratch? Do you always see data loss? At 52k docs?

Comment: Let me create the cURL as well as re-inject the data.

Answer (score 0):

dadoonet is probably right about the delete request. Another thing that could potentially happen is if you were using the default data path then the Elasticsearch data was being stored in the elasticsearch folder itself. If someone deployed a new version of elasticsearch on top of the existing one, then you would lose data.